# A question about absolute continuity and differentiability of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be an absolute continuous on $[0,1].$ Suppose that there exists a continuous function 
$p:[0,1]\rightarrow R_{+}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}p(x)=0$ such that for any Lebesgue points 
$\xi, \eta\in [0,1]$ of $f'$ we have
$$
|f'(\xi)-f'(\eta)|\leq \mathrm{const}\cdot p(|\xi-\eta|).
$$

Question: Is $f$ a $C^{1}_{[0,1]}$ function?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: @copper. I think this function does not satisfy